# Is every connected Lie subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{C}^n$ already a complex vector subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups, complex-geometry

I wonder if every connected Lie subgroup of the additive group $\mathbb{C}^n$ already is a complex vector subspace. This seems correct to me. In general, I would be happy to find a good book on complex Lie groups.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: What if we moreover assume that the subgroup is a global analytic set in $\mathbb{C}^n$, i.e. the vanishing set of some holomorphic functions  in several variables?

Comment: Every connected abelian complex Lie group is a quotient of $\Bbb C^n$ by a lattice in $\Bbb C^n$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So for example a usual torus embedded into some $\mathbb{C}^n$ would also be possible? What happens if we moreover assume that the Lie Group is a global analytic set, i.e. the vanishing set of holomorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: How about the embedding of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ into $\mathbb{C}^2$? In general, the torus $(\mathbb{C}^\times)^n$ embeds into $\mathbb{C}^{2n}$ as a closed set.

Comment: @Levent: that's not a subgroup. But (for the original question, not the new question) how about the embedding of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connected Lie subgroups of $\mathbb{C}^n$ are exactly the *real* vector subspaces. We can see this as follows: the connected abelian Lie groups are all products of copies of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$ (e.g. by considering the exponential map from their Lie algebras). Since $\mathbb{C}^n$, as a group, is torsion-free, all its subgroups must be torsion-free, which means $S^1$ can't occur as a subgroup. So the connected Lie subgroups must have the form $\mathbb{R}^k$ for some $k$, and smooth homomorphisms $\mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{C}^n$ must be $\mathbb{R}$-linear (in fact much weaker conditions would suffice, continuity or even measurability; this is related to the [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation)).

If by Lie group you meant "complex Lie group" then Dietrich Burde's argument in the comments finishes it; the same exponential map argument as above shows that the connected abelian complex Lie groups are all quotients of $\mathbb{C}^k$ by a lattice, and then torsion-freeness implies the lattice must be trivial, so we get $\mathbb{C}^k$ on the nose, and similarly holomorphic homomorphisms $\mathbb{C}^k \to \mathbb{C}^n$ must be $\mathbb{C}$-linear.

Comment: We should be able to show that the connected topological subgroups, not necessarily Lie, are the real vector subspaces, but the argument eludes me for the moment. I can do it for path-connected subgroups.

Comment: Thank you very much!